# Windows SDK - Only for DirectX-Apps?

Tags: windows-8, directx, directx-11

because I habe problems installing the DirectX SDK June (11), I read that Windows 8.1 users already have the DirectX 11 SDK integrated - in the Windows-SDK. But nevertheless, I could not get the info (even not from MCs article "Where is the DirectX SDK) if this SDK only offers the possibility to write DirectX-Apps (Win 8-Apps). If it also supports writing normal desktop-programs:
Do you know how I can set up a normal Win32-Project using DirectX from the Windows-SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma region COM
#include <guiddef.h>
#include <OCIdl.h>
#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <Objbase.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ole32.lib")
#include <OleCtl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "OleAut32.lib")

#include <comutil.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppwd.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")
#endif

#pragma region WIC
#include <wincodecsdk.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "windowscodecs.lib")
#pragma endregion

#pragma region D2D
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2dbasetypes.h>
#include <d2d1helper.h>
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <d2d1_1helper.h>
#include <d2d1_2.h>
#include <d2d1_2helper.h>
#include <d2d1effects.h>
#include <d2d1effecthelpers.h>
#include <d2d1effectauthor.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")
#pragma endregion

#pragma region DWrite
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <dwrite_1.h>
#include <dwrite_2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"dwrite.lib")
#pragma endregion

#pragma region D3D
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
#include <d3d11_2.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <DirectXColors.h>
#include <DirectXCollision.h>
#include <DirectXPackedVector.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#ifdef _DEBUG
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")
#endif
#pragma endregion

#pragma region XAudio
#include <Xaudio2.h>
#include <x3daudio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Xaudio2.lib")
#pragma endregion
```

**WIN32 SDK D3D + D2D + XAudio + WIC** includes and static libs. Put these in your `pch.h` or `stdafx.h` after `<windows.h>`.

And the [**Desktop DirectX Graphics Reference** links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663274.aspx):

- [Direct3D11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh309466.aspx)
- [Direct2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990.aspx)
- [DirectWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038.aspx)
- [XAudio2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405049.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible to writing an normal Directx desktop programs with the Win8 SDK since DirectX SDK now a part of the Windows SDK, and you can build a desktop app with the Windows8 SDK just like old DirectX SDK just include your header, link your library and write your app, Just be aware that this SDK don't supports writing app to older version of DirectX (DirectX9, 10) and older it's only supports DirectX11,
If you want to writ a app to older version of DirectX then use the old one SDK

Comment: And how exactly do I bind the DirectX-Headers etc... into my VS-Project?
Project-Settings->VC++-Directories....?

Comment: With Win8 SDk you don't need to do anything Just include DX headers but with the old one you have to link the directories that containing the headers  and LIBs, The "Where is the DirectX SDK" article and exactly "Using DirectX SDK projects with Visual Studio" Explains how to do this.
There is another document that comes with old DIrectX SDK Explains in detail how to setting up DX SDK.